# tinymce - how to remove styles added via style_formats

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I've defined some formats via style_formats option, and after I use it, the only way I know to remove them is to edit HTML source. Is there any option to remove it by clicking repeatedly or defining new button?

```
            style_formats: [
            {title: 'Grey background', selector: 'p,ul,div', styles: {
                    'background-color': '#e9e9e9',
                    'border-radius': '5px',
                    'padding': '1em'
                }}
            ],
```

Clear formatting button does not work.